# Audio noise/feedback through speakers from HDMI (DIY projector)

Tags: audio, feedback, hdmi

I have built a projector and it's mostly working except I'm having issues with speaker noise, I'm not an expert with this sort of thing at all so I'll try my best to explain.

I have 12 V DC coming into the projector from an AC to DC power supply, the positive and negative then go to separate bus bars, all the other components connect to these bus bars.

For simplicity sake I will just include the screen and amp/speaker setup as I have removed everything else from the projector to track down the issue.

The screen has a driver board with HDMI input, 5 V in (USB or direct) and 3.5 mm audio jack output.

The amp is just a little TPA3110 30 W + 30 W.

If I hook up the driver board to power (I have tried two different supply boards, both USB supply and a buck converter), HDMI input and a 3.5 mm audio cable. I will get audio and video but with a bad crackling noise coming through the speakers. This noise is only present when plugging the HDMI cable into the control board.

If I plug the audio cable into a phone or computer with nothing else connected, there is no crackling; as soon as I plug the HDMI cable into the board, the crackling starts.

Things I've tried that don't work:

- Different power supplies to HDMI control board
- Different HDMI cables to control board
- Using a HDMI audio splitter before the HDMI control board (same crackling noise)
- Plugging the HDMI cable into a computer and the 3.5 mm audio cable directly into a computer instead of using the control board or splitter to split the audio

Things that do work:

- Unplugging HDMI cable from control board
- Powering the control board or amp from a second power source, this can be USB or another AC to DC power supply, both ways worked in removing the crackling noise

So I've kind of found a solution, but I don't want to use two separate power supplies going into the projector as I'm sure there must be a better solution.

Thank you if you made it this far, I hope I explained myself correctly.

Comment: Which boards and modules and supplies these are and how these are wired together? We really need to "see" the system and the wiring to understand what causes the problem and how to fix it. Randomly wiring random modules together rarely ends up well.

Comment: _”bad crackling noise”_ As in switch mode subharmonics, 6-8 kHz feedback loop or something else?